# Is there a simple way to do a "polar" plot with arbitrary angle axes?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'd like to use a polar plot to visualize data, but the "angle" value is not actually angle.  For example:

```
polarplot(mod(X,a)*2*pi/a, Y)
```

I'm just visualizing `X` as wrapped modulo `a`.

So, on my polar plot I'd like the angle axis to go 0 to a instead of 0 to 360 (or 0 to 2pi).  Is there a straightforward way?

Comment: Not sure if this counts as straighforward, but you can manually change the tick labels: `h = gca; h.ThetaTickLabel = h.ThetaTick'/360*a;`